# Write and Read at the Same Time - C

Tags: c

This is a sketch how I want to write a .txt:

```
time_t timer;
struct tm y2k = { 0 };
int seconds;
int seconds_prev= 0;
int i = 0;
y2k.tm_hour = 0;   y2k.tm_min = 0; y2k.tm_sec = 0;
y2k.tm_year = 100; y2k.tm_mon = 0; y2k.tm_mday = 1;

FILE *f = fopen("file.txt", "w");

if (f == NULL)
{
    printf("Error opening file!\n");
    return 0;
}

for (;;){

    time(&timer);   
    seconds = difftime(timer, mktime(&y2k));

    if (seconds % 2 == 0 && seconds!=seconds_prev) {
        seconds_prev= seconds;
        const char *text = "AAAAAA";
        fprintf(f, "%d-%s\n",i, text);
        fflush(f);
        i++
        if (i == 20){
            break;
        }
    }
}

fclose(f);
```

This script enable writing roughly 1 line per second in a text file.
Now I want to read this file until it is complete.

```
FILE *file;
size_t nread;

file = fopen("file.txt", "r");
if (file) {
    /*pseudo code*/
    //(reading loop)
    //(some condition that detects the true end of file writing)
    //(buffering information)
    //(end of loop)
    /**************/

    if (ferror(file)) {
        /* deal with error */
    }
    fclose(file);
}
```

So the main objective is to read the "file.txt" while it is been writing. The big problem that I face, is the fact that the script only reads the information already written and stops the reading. I am searching some condition, flag, etc that me let resolve this problem. So far, nothing

Comment: Do you need the output to go to an intermediate file? If not, just read/write form stdin/out and pipe the output of the first command into the second.

Comment: @Bizkit (and Borgleader) You sure? `cout << i << endl;` Seems to be shitty C++.

Comment: Use r+ mode so that file will be open for both reading & writing

Comment: Unfortunately I need, for future applications. It happens that i have nodejs addon and i cannot make pipes between nodejs(exe) and addon(dll). I want to interpret audio streaming while it arrive. So I am trying a way of reading wav while it arrives. This is the start-up exemple for me.

Comment: Rough idea - the thing which you want can be implemented by using two file pointer , one for reading & one for writing. Writing file pointer will occur first , then reading file pointer will occur. There will be one loop for(;;) inside it writing pointer will write first line ; then reading pointer will read that line and it will continue till eof.. this is just rough idea.

Comment: I would look into using `read()` and `write()` instead of standard library io.

Also, you maybe can still create pipes.  You can create pipes at the OS level and as far as your applications know, they're just reading from and writing to files still.

Comment: You can also do `prog1 | tee out.txt | prog2` (`tee` takes stdin and both saves it to a file and echoes it to stdout)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this with *named pipes*.  nodejs shouldn't matter for this because as far as your programs are concerned, it's just a normal file.

#### Read session

```
$ mkfifo text.fifo
$ cat text.fifo
```

#### foo.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
  FILE * f = fopen ("text.fifo", "w");

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
  {
    fprintf (f, "Sup %d\n", i);
    fflush (f);
    sleep(1);
  }

  fclose(f);

  return 0;
}
```

#### Write Session

```
$ gcc foo.c -std=c99
$ ./a.exe
$
```

#### Read Session

```
$ mkfifo text.fifo
$ cat text.fifo
Sup 0
Sup 1
Sup 2
Sup 3
Sup 4
Sup 5
Sup 6
Sup 7
Sup 8
Sup 9

$
```

Comment: You didn't specify OS, but the above example was on cygwin

Answer (score 0):

My ugly final solution:

**writer:**

```
for (;;){`

   //printing single chatacters
   char c[25] = "ABCDEFGHIJLMNOPQRSTUVXZ";

    //fprintf(f, "A character: %c\n", c[i]);
    fprintf(f, "-%c", c[i]);
    fflush(f);
    printf("-%c", c[i]);
    i++;
    _sleep(1000);
    if (i == 20){
        break;
    }

    fclose(f);
```

**reader:**

```
file = fopen("file.txt", "r");

if (file) {
    //while (((nread = fread(buf, 1, sizeof buf, file)) > 0)){
    while ((((nread = fread(buf, 1, sizeof buf, file)) >= 0))){
        fwrite(buf, 1, nread, stdout);
        //_sleep(1000);

        int size= sizeof buf;
        for (int i = 0; size; i++){
            if (buf[i] == 'R') { //my [eof]
                out = 1;
                break;
            }
            if (i == 10){//preventing buf[] empty - need improvement
                break;
            }
        }
        if (out== 1) break;
    }
    if (ferror(file)) {
        printf("Bad. \n");
    }
    fclose(file);
}
```

Is not very efficient but works fine.